# Is it worth killing all the monsters in each floor in Sword and Poker 2?

Tags: sword-and-poker-2

I try to get all the chests and kill all the golden monsters but I don't know if it is worth chasing the rest of the monsters (if I have to use a recharge coin I lose its bonus at the end of the floor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing *every* enemy in the later dungeons is a little redundant; I just leave the floor after getting all the rewards and golden monsters.